# How can I access to DOM attribute with variable in PhantomJS function ?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I use Javascript with PhantomJS.
I know my DOM contain many attribute like foo_0, foo_1, … 
I know I can access them with (I test it, It's work)

```
window.foo_1.src
window['foo_1'].src
```

I would like iterate to access all attributes. Something like this:

```
var i = 0
do {
    // some stuff
    bar = page.evaluate(function(){
        return window['foo_' + i].src
    })
    i++
} while ( <cond> )
```

'foo_1' work fine but 'foo_' + i don't.

Do you have any idea ? 
I seems not know.

Comment: Exact your link seems respond to my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Variable *i* is not know in function evaluate. Add argument and it's work ! Just like this.

```
var i = 0
do {
    // some stuff
    bar = page.evaluate(function(i){
        return window['foo_' + i].src
    }, i)
    i++
} while ( <cond> )
```